# echoing multiple arguments when output_buffering is on

Tags: php, performance, string, output-buffering

One of *Googles Let's make the internet faster* talks included something about using echo with multiple arguments in PHP instead of using print or string concatenation.

```
echo 'The ball is ', $color;
```

Rather than either of these

```
echo "The ball is $color";
echo 'The ball is ' . $color;
```

What if output buffering is in play ?

What would be the difference between using echo with multiple arguments along with output buffering, vs using the alternate methods without output buffering ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to read the [PHP team's rebuttal](http://groups.google.com/group/make-the-web-faster/browse_thread/thread/ddfbe82dd80408cc) of [Google's performance tips](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html).

Specifically, he (Gwynne Raskind) says:

> 4) "Don't use concatenation with echo."
>
> This is exactly the opposite of correct advice. The engine handles 
>   multiple arguments to echo() in such a way that concatenation (or 
>   double-quoted string interpolation) is actually much faster. See the 
>   benchmark posted at http://pastie.org/523020.

Comment: And even if you put a loooot more stress on the heap the concat-version is a lot faster. I still prefer the echo a,b,c format (for no good reason but habit)

Answer (score 1):

the first version should be a bit faster because it doesn't have to parse the string for variable expansion (single quotes) and it doesn't have to spend time concatenating the two strings before writing them. i don't think that buffering will affect this

Comment: But if output buffering was on, wouldn't that cause the first version to do everything the later versions do in order to fill the output buffer ?

Comment: Not really. With the "...$x..." version PHP first expands the strings (i.e. create a new string) and then passes it to echo regardless of whether there is an output buffer or not. But anyway read mercator's answer. (Never substitute a performance test by assumptions ;-))